# Rxjs: Assigning a subject.pipe() to an observable in Angular ngOnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs

The template has an input listening to keyUp event. The component has an Observable and a Subject. The Subject is piped with operators that will map the string value from the input into a Stock[] Observable.
On every keyUp event the Subject emits the next event with a new value from the input.

template:

```
<div>
<input  name="searchBox"
        [(ngModel)]="searchString"
        placeholder="Search here"
        (keyup)="search()">
</div>

<h2>
     We have found {{ (stocks$ | async )?.length }} stocks!
</h2>
 <app-stock-item *ngFor="let stock of stocks$ | async"
            [stock]="stock"
>

</app-stock-item>
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {StockService} from '../../services/stock.service';
import {Stock} from '../../model/stock';

import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

import {debounceTime,switchMap,distinctUntilChanged,
    startWith, share} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-stock-list',
   templateUrl: './stock-list.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./stock-list.component.css']
})
export class StockListComponent implements OnInit {

  public stocks$!: Observable<Stock[]>;

  public searchString:string = "";

  private searchTerms:Subject<string> = new Subject();

  constructor(private stockService:StockService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  console.log(this.stocks$);

                  // how does this work after ngOnInit is executed?
  this.stocks$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
                  startWith(this.searchString),
                  debounceTime(500),
                  distinctUntilChanged(),
                  //getStocks returns an Observable of HttpClient
                  switchMap( (query) => this.stockService.getStocks(query)),
                  share()
      );


  }


  search(){

    this.searchTerms.next(this.searchString);

  }

}
```

If ngOnInit is called only once every rendering of the component, why Subject.pipe() and Subject.next() still works after the ngOnInit finishes its execution? does the Subject gets subscribed anywhere in the code?

Comment: It works because you've got two [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) usages in your template. Both implicitly create subscriptions.

Comment: @miqh so when the Observable is subscribed the Subject also gets subscribed?

Comment: The way I think of it is that those async pipes are subscribed to the `stocks$` observable. The definition of `stocks$` happens to be based off the `searchTerms` subject. In other words, the async pipes don't create a direct subscription to the underlying subject—nor would it make sense in my opinion, unless you had something in the template in which you wanted to display the current `searchTerms` value (i.e. via another async pipe).

Comment: Is the operators in the subject's pipe saved somewhere? how do the operators not get destroyed after the ngOnInit is finished?

Comment: That's part of the observable definition—just because execution leaves `ngOnInit()` doesn't mean the observable disappears. `stocks$` is scoped to the lifetime of the component. The async pipe subscriptions get destroyed when the component gets destroyed (if you read the documentation I linked above).

Comment: Okay, then how does the `this.searchTerms.next()` work? Does the observable definition runs again every time the `next()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Very simplified picture is:

```
searchTerms = {
  subscriptionFn: null,
  next: function(query) {
    this.subscriptionFn(query);
  }
};
stocks$ = {value: null};
    
    
ngOnInit() {
  this.searchTerms.subscriptionFn = (query) => this.stockService.getStocks(query).subscribe(value => this.stocks$.value = value);
}

search(){

  this.searchTerms.next(this.searchString);

}
```

And html async pipe will be just `{{stocks$.value}}`.
There are lots of differences - e.g. switchMap will cancel old request, when new raises etc., but ~~~ this code is doing same.

Comment: So the subject and the observable share the same subscription object?